# Let $a_{i,i+1} = c_i$ for $i=1,...n$, Prove that the determinant of $I + A + A^2 + ... + A^n = (1-c)^{n-1}$ where $c = c_1...c_n$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-explanation, determinant

For a matrix $A$, Let $a_{i,i+1} = c_i$ for $i=1,...n$, and the other matrix elements are zero.

Prove that the determinant of $I + A + A^2 + ... + A^n = (1-c)^{n-1}$

where $c = c_1...c_n$

The problem is from
http://staff.math.su.se/mleites/books/prasolov-1994-problems.pdf

Here is its original wording and solution. Can someone explain it for me? still confused even after reading it.

[image]

[image]

Comment: We're missing something here.  Is $A$ $n \times n$? If so, then should $a_{n,n+1}$ really be $a_{n,1}$? Note that this statement is false if $A$ is $(n+1) \times (n+1)$ or bigger.

Comment: as the problem is phrased, the relation between $A$ and the $a_{k\ k+1}$ is not completely clear; do you mean to say that they are the $(k, k+1)$ entries of $A$? using the notation $A_{k\ l}$ for the $(k, l)$ entry of $A$ would eliminate any lack of clarity; also, $A$ is given as a square matrix of what order over what ring?

Comment: If I have understood the problem correctly, then you could use the formula for the determinant of a [circulant matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix#Determinant)

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I added more edits.

Comment: @ΑΘΩ I added more edits

Comment: The way that transformation is described would suggest that the matrix is strictly upper triangular, with entry $c_k$ at position $(k+1, k)$; however, if that is the case than $A$ is automatically nilpotent, so $A^n$ being scalar no longer makes sense (unless we had $n=0$ ). Not meaning to deterr you from the study of  serious mathematics, but such glaring cases of textbook slopiness&silliness will profit you nothing, so don't waste too much time on them.

Comment: @ΑΘΩ thank you, I will close the question

Comment: please don't take my words above as a criticism, for all that this site is concerned perhaps the question could just as well remain posted (it wouldn't be such an issue), what I did mean to convey to you is a certain need to cultivate the spirit of discerning what textbooks to invest time and effort in and which ones you could just as well ignore.

Comment: @ΑΘΩ understood. absolutely appreciate your comments.

Comment: I think that if we do a little archaeology here, we can recover the main ideas. (i) we're working over $\Bbb R$. (ii) indices are to be taken mod $n$, and $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix. Those assumptions seem to explain the reasoning in the original solution, anyhow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As John Hughes and I have indicated in the comments, the indices are meant to be taken modulo $n$.  So for instance in the case of $n = 4$, the matrix $A$ we are talking about is
$$
A = \pmatrix{&c_1\\&&c_2\\&&&c_3\\c_4}
$$
with the blank entries equal to zero. With that established, the steps in the solution make sense; we need only verify that $\det(I - A) = 1-c$.  That is, we need to compute the determinant of 
$$
I - A = \pmatrix{1&-c_1\\&1&-c_2\\&&\ddots&\ddots\\ &&&&-c_{n-1}\\-c_n&&&&1}.
$$
If we use the [Laplace expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_expansion) along the final row, we have
$$
\det(I - A) = (-1)^{n-1}\cdot  (-c_n) \det(M_1) + 1 \cdot \det(M_2),
$$
where 
$$
M_1 = \pmatrix{-c_1\\1&-c_2\\&\ddots&\ddots\\ &&&-c_{n-2}\\ &&&1&-c_{n-1}}, \\
M_2 = \pmatrix{1&-c_1 \\ & 1&-c_2\\ &&\ddots&\ddots\\&&&&-c_{n-2} \\ &&&&1}.
$$
Because $M_1$ and $M_2$ are lower and upper triangular respectively, we quickly find that $\det(M_1) = (-1)^{n-1} c_1 \dots c_{n-1}$ and $\det(M_2) = 1$. The conclusion follows.